# Eiffel: Can I use `expanded SOME_DEFERRED_CLASS`?

Tags: polymorphism, abstract-class, instantiation, eiffel

`x: expanded SOME_DEFERRED_CLASS` is impossible because:

1. A `deferred` class cannot be used for object instantiation.
2. An `expanded` type does not allow [polymorphism](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~eiffel/ISE/doc/html/manuals/language/intro/polymorphism.maker.html).

Have I missed something, or am I right?

Answer (score 2):

`x: expanded A_CLASS` is an obsolete syntax. It is no longer supported.

However `expanded` can be used in a class definition. In this case, as you cited, it is not possible to have both a deferred and an expanded class.

As a simple rule, it is possible to define a class with only one from the next list: `expanded`, `deferred`, `separate`, `frozen`.

If you whish "expand" an already existing implementation, you just need to create an expanded heir of this class. Take a look to the Eiffel's kernel library, you can find examples of this (e.g. `INTEGER_32` - an expanded class - inherits of `INTEGER_32_REF`)

Comment: *"`x: expanded A_CLASS` is an obsolete syntax. It is no longer supported."* ← Wow, I hadn't the slightest idea! Thank you! By the way, where did you find this information? Could you post a link for future reference?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. The reasoning can be rephrased as follows:

1. No type conforms *directly* to an expanded type.
2. If a type is expanded, it conforms only to itself. (From 1. There are more conformance rules but for expanded types they can involve only generic parameters at most.)
3. An entity of a particular type can be used only if it is properly set.
4. An entity of an expanded type can be used only if it is instantiated with an object of the same type. (From 2 and 3.)
5. A deferred type cannot be used for instantiation.
6. An entity of a deferred expanded type cannot be used. (From 4 and 5.)

So, even though technically it might be possible to allow for declaration of entities of a deferred expanded type, they could not be used.

As correctly pointed out in the other answer, in the modern Eiffel, only one class mark can be used to indicate its status, and therefore, it's syntactically impossible to declare a deferred expanded class or type. However, even it were allowed, it would be useless.

**EDIT:**

There are two kinds of conformance: *direct* and *general*. Direct conformance reflects parent-child relationship: there are no transitivity or reflexivity rules, a special rule for the type `NONE`, etc. It basically states, that if a class `C` inherits from a class `P`, then the type `C` conforms to the type `P` under certain conditions. The conditions rule out the case when `C` is expanded.

General conformance uses direct conformance as one of the base cases together with some others, e.g. a reflexivity rule "*a type conforms to itself*". Therefore, the rule "*no type directly conforms to an expanded type*" simply means inheritance links do not matter for expanded types. But due to the reflexivity rule an expanded type still conforms to itself.

All these details behind the note "*From 1*". More information can be found in the [Standard ECMA-367](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-367.htm) (section 8.14).

Comment: Imagine classes `P` (parent class) and `C` (child class), where `C` inherits from `P`:

Comment: If `P` and `C` are not expanded classes, then type C conforms to type P, but not vice-versa. But if `P` or `C` (or both) were expanded, neither type C would conform to P nor vice-versa, because *"No type conforms directly to an expanded type."*.

Comment: What I want to discuss is № 2: *"If a type is expanded, it conforms only to itself. (**From 1.** There are more conformance rules but for expanded types they can involve only generic parameters at most.)"*. How come "From 1"? How can this be logically valid? № 1 tells us that *"No type conforms directly to an expanded type."*, but type conformance doesn't work both ways: if type C conforms to type P, that doesn't mean that type P conforms to type C. Hence, *"From 1."* must be wrong, don't you agree? Or has it got something to do with the use of the word *"directly"* in № 1? What does it mean?

Comment: @g4v3, Indeed, there is a notion of conformance and direct conformance. I'll add some details to the answer for clarification.